# Checkout settings are ignored

Tags: ubercart

I have configurations on store>configuration>completion messages. But they are not reflecting on the site. For example I have set the checkout page as a node I created but it's still using the default checkout page. I have cleared all the cache. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the checkout page is dynamically generated by Ubercart, you cannot create a node for it. You can theme the dynamically generated page or alter it through custom modules if needed, see several very helpful Ubercart tutorials here: https://drupal.org/project/ubercart

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand you because Ubercart has a setting called "Alternate checkout completion page" Please see my screenshots.

[link]http://www.beatscent.co.za/old2/checkout2.PNG

[link]http://www.beatscent.co.za/old2/checkout.PNG

Comment: I believe that this allows you to change the path of that page, but it is still generated by Ubercart. So you can have it point to mysite.com/buy for example instead of mysite.com/cart. But if you create a node with that path (mysite.com/buy) the programmatically created checkout page from Ubercart will be overridden and all the code that Ubercart needs to execute to make the cart work will not be there. What features are you trying to add to the default checkout page?

Comment: Thanks for the info :-) I have solved it in another way. I have create a block that only appears on the checkout page using the context module ;-)

Comment: Glad you solved it. I'm curious - did you end up using the Ubercart checkout page or were you able to use the node page you created?

Comment: I wasn't able to use the node I created. But I still cannot see the additional config I did, If you look at my last screenshot on my previous comment. Where does the **Message Header** appear?

Comment: the links to the screenshots don't work...

Comment: http://www.beatscent.co.za/old2/checkout.PNG